# Does a hasMany relationship in GORM require an indexColumn?

Tags: grails, mapping, grails-orm

I'm dealing with legacy tables right now.  Our Grails app will simply display data.  All data entry and updates take place using a different tool.  It would be very difficult to add columns to the legacy database.  Are indexColumns absolutely, positively required?  Or is there some way I can simply not use indexColumns at all in this case?

http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/indexColumn.html

Answer (score 0):

Not if it is a `Set`, which is the default type for `hasMany` relationships.

> By default when mapping an indexed collection such as a Map or List the index is stored in a column called association_name_idx

[Grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/indexColumn.html)